# MySQL SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE smth AND a field from another table is something

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. One contains information on hotels, added to my website by users. It contains a field called Username that contains the username of the person that has uploaded it. The second table contains user info (including a field called "active" which indicates if a user has paid or not). I need to get entries from the first table ONLY for users that have paid. Currently I'm doing it like this in PHP:

```
$hotelsq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trips_all ORDER BY id DESC ");
while ($hotel = mysql_fetch_array($hotelsq)) {
    $username = $hotel['username'];
    $isactiq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $isact = mysql_fetch_array($isactiq);
    if ($isact['active'] == 'member') {
```

What I need is a single query that will select all of the hotels in the first table, then check if the user ("username" column) it has been uploaded from has "member" in the "active" column. The username column in the second table is named "username" as well.
What would that query look like ?

Comment: I wanna make my username = '; drop table users; -- so bad right now.

Comment: thats called SQL injection DreamWave you should look into it

Comment: actually DampeS8N since thats a while loop you could drop his whole database

Comment: @DampeS8N: yes there's a SQL injection exploit there, but `mysql_query` will only ever run one query, so you wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: yes yes. It is the thought that counts. I could create a user that would look like an admin. That would be as easy as finding an admin's username and making my username "' or username = 'that admin"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select t.*
from trips_all t
inner join users on t.username = u.username
    where u.active = 'member'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check INNER JOIN:

[SQL INNER JOIN Keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

So something along the lines of:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trips_all INNER JOIN users ON trips_all.username=users.username WHERE users.active='member');
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Where should ORDER BY id DESC be in that line ?

Comment: That query returns IDs from the users column, instead of trips_all ids.. how do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from trips_all t
left join users u on t.id= u.userid
where u.active = 'member'
```

Comment: -1: Not sure why this has two votes — besides joining on non-existent columns, the query returns all trips.